# DataGridView c#, making a new a custom "fill" method

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, dataset, tableadapter

I have a table on the db, which is shown on 2 different datagridviews, but, one is filled by default, showing all the data on the table, and the second one I want to be filled with a condition. 
So I'd like to fill that table initialy with a custom select query. How can I achieve that?

pd: I use datasets, in which I created the custom query, so the question should be how do I fill by default a table with certain tableadapter I made.

Comment: Use a [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Use 2 different TableAdapter with 2 different select query.

Answer (score 0):

if you can share your codes, you will find a most right answer quickly.

```
            var query = db.table.Where(x=>x.column1==condition1).ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = query ();   dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Or, if you have filled datatable/dataset you can write

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = yourDataTable;   dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter the data in your DataSet then set the DataSource of your DataGridView to a DataTable created by that filter.  The code would look something like:

```
// Need to create a DataView from your original DataSet
// and set the view to the default view from your DataSet.
DataView view = new DataView();
view = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

// Next, create a filter on that view
view.RowFilter = "State = 'CA'";

// Now create a DataTable from the view
// and set the DataSource of the DataGridView to that DataTable.
DataTable dt = view.ToTable("tablename");
dgrdToDisplay.DataSource = dt;
```